# SQL Update Or Insert By Comparing Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do the UPDATE or INSERT, but I am not sure if this is possible without using loop. Here is the example:

Says, I have this SQL below in which I joined two tables: tblCompany and tblOrders.

```
SELECT CompanyID, CompanyName, c.LastSaleDate, o.SalesOrderID, o.SalesPrice
, DATEADD(m, -6, GETDATE()) AS DateLast6MonthFromToday
FROM dbo.tblCompany c
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 SalesOrderID, SalesPrice
    FROM dbo.tblOrders o
    WHERE c.CompanyID = o.CompanyID
    ORDER BY SalesOrderID DESC
    ) AS a
WHERE Type = 'End-User'
```

Sample Result:

```
CompanyID, SalesOrderID, SalesPrice, LastSalesDate, DateLast6MonthFromToday
101        10001         50          2/01/2016   10/20/2016
102        10002         80          12/01/2016  10/20/2016
103        10003         80          5/01/2016   10/20/2016
```

What I am trying to do is comparing the LastSalesDate and the DateLast6MonthFromToday. Condition is below:

- If the LastSalesDate is lesser (earlier), then do the INSERT INTO tblOrders (CompanyID, Column1, Column2...) VALUES (CompanyIDFromQuery, Column1Value, Column2Value)
- Else, do UPDATE tblOrders SET SalesPrice = 1111 WHERE SalesOrderID = a.SalesOrderID

As the above sample result, the query will only update SalesOrderID 10001 and 10003. And For Company 102, NO insert since the LastSaleDate is greater, then just do the UPDATE for the SalesOrderID.

I know it is probably can be done if I create a Cursor to loop through every record and do the comparison then Update or Insert, but I wonder if there is another way perform this without the loop since I have around 20K records.

Sorry for the confusion,

Comment: you should atleast show the schema of the tables and tell us how they can be joined.

Comment: i don't understand the issue here. why can't you just execute insert and update statements

Comment: Give your sample table data..

Comment: short answer is can't have insert and update on the same statement

Comment: Use merge statement.

Comment: @Milacay can you add some data from this two tables like an example?

Comment: If you only want to define the logic _once_ then this can be done using a `merge` statement but it gets pretty enormous. If you don't mind defining the logic twice then you can use seperate `insert` and `update` statements. The middle ground is to create a view based on this statement then use that in seperate `insert` and `update` statements. Many options, no answer ;). Would you prefer to create a view or create a long `merge` statement? How is this currently run? usually you would wrap all of this up in a stored procedure

Comment: Before I attempt to answer ... since the table you are inserting-into-and/or-updating is `tblOrders` and that is also one of the source tables is it possible for one row being inserted/updated to change what would happen with the subsequent rows? If not, a temp table and two statements (one insert and one update) should do the trick. If so, it could be very messy!

Comment: which table need to be updated/inserted and with what value ?what is the purpose of above query ?Yes no need of cursor or loop and 20k records can be updatec easily else we can use paging.

Comment: Thank you for all the advice.  Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your tables structure and your data types. Also I know nothing
about duplicates and join ralationships between this 2 tables.
But I want only show how it works on next example:

```
use [your test db];
go

create table dbo.tblCompany
(
    companyid int,
    companyname varchar(max),
    lastsaledate datetime,
    [type] varchar(max)
);

create table dbo.tblOrders 
(
    CompanyID int, 
    SalesOrderID int, 
    SalesPrice float
);


insert into dbo.tblCompany 
values
    (1, 'Avito', '2016-01-01', 'End-User'),
    (2, 'BMW', '2016-05-01', 'End-User'),
    (3, 'PornHub', '2017-01-01', 'End-User')

insert into dbo.tblOrders
values
    (1, 1, 500),
    (1, 2, 700),
    (1, 3, 900),
    (2, 1, 500),
    (2, 2, 700),
    (2, 3, 900),
    (3, 1, 500),
    (3, 2, 700),
    (3, 3, 900)

declare @column_1_value int = 5;
declare @column_2_value int = 777;

with cte as (
    select
        CompanyID,
        SalesOrderID,
        SalesPrice 
    from (
        select 
            CompanyID,
            SalesOrderID, 
            SalesPrice, 
            row_number() over(partition by CompanyID order by SalesOrderId desc) as rn
        from 
            dbo.tblOrders
    ) t
    where rn = 1
)

merge cte as target 
using (select * from dbo.tblCompany where [type] = 'End-User')  as source
    on target.companyid = source.companyid
    and source.lastsaledate >= dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
when matched 
    then update set target.salesprice = 1111
when not matched
    then insert (
        CompanyID,
        SalesOrderID,
        SalesPrice
    )
    values (
        source.CompanyId,
        @column_1_value,
        @column_2_value
    );

select * from dbo.tblOrders
```

***If you will give me an information, then I can prepare target and source tables properly.***

Comment: Thank you so much for the sample code.  It looks very complicated to me, but I am going to try and let you know.

Comment: Your solution is perfect.  I followed your sample and saw how it works.  Then applied that logic to my situation, and it worked great.  Without the sample code, I wouldn't be able to figure that out. Thank you again.

Comment: @Milacay In all cases please be carefull, because in merge statement you can not update 1 row twice.

Comment: I see.  Thanks again!